# Newton's second law with variable mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass

Let's say there's a body that is being affected only by a constant force $F$, but the body is vaporizing at the speed $β$, which is equal to the loss of some mass every second. The initial speed of the body is 0. What would be a function for acceleration versus time and for speed versus time? The initial mass is $m_0$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
F&=\frac{dp}{dt}\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}(mv)\\
&=\dot mv+m\dot v\\
&=-\beta v+ma
\end{align}
Here I defined $\beta\equiv -\dot m$ as the mass evaporation rate to make $\beta$ positive. I assume $\beta$ is constant which gives $m(t)=m_0-\beta t$. This results in the following differential equation
$$(m_0-\beta t)\ddot x(t)-\beta\dot x(t)-F=0$$
Plugging that into Mathematica gives after some rearranging
$$x(t)=\frac F\beta \left(\frac\beta{m_0}\right)^{-1}\left[-t\frac\beta{m_0}-\log\left(1-t\frac\beta{m_0}\right)\right]$$
Here $F/\beta$ and $\beta/m_0$ are quantities that naturally popped up during the rearranging. They have units of $LT^{-1}$ and $T^{-1}$ respectively. Compare this solution to the case where $\beta=0$
$$x(t)=\frac{F}{2m_0}t^2$$
I plotted these solutions for a couple different values of $\beta/m_0$ where I kept $\frac F\beta \left(\frac\beta{m_0}\right)^{-1} =1$ and I included $\beta=0$ as a separate case because it has a different solution. This looks as follows

[image]

Note that the solutions stop existing if $t\geq(\beta/m_0)^{-1}$ which corresponds to the mass becoming less than zero, i.e. when the particle stops existing.

---

Mathematica code:

```
(* Solving the differential equations *)
DSolve[{(m0 - \[Beta] t) x''[t] - \[Beta] x'[t] - F == 0, x[0] == 0, 
  x'[0] == 0}, x, t]
DSolve[{(m0) x''[t] - F == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x, t]

(* input the simplified function with a==F/beta, b==beta/m0 *)
sol1[t_, a_, b_] := a (b)^-1 (-t b - Log[1 - t b])
sol2[t_, a_, b_] := (a b)/2 t^2

(* enforce a*b==1 *)
sol3[t_,x_]:=sol1[t,1/x,x]
sol4[t_,x_]:=sol2[t,1/x,x]

Plot[Evaluate[{ sol3[t, .5], sol3[t, 1], sol3[t, 4], 
   sol4[t, 1/1, 1]}], {t, 0, 1}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"t", "x"}, 
   Frame -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> {"\[Beta]/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(0\)]\) = 0.5", 
   "\[Beta]/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(0\)]\) = 1", 
   "\[Beta]/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(0\)]\) = 4", 
   "\[Beta] = 0 (Constant mass)"}]
```

Comment: Would like to add that for high B values, and for high T value, relativity would change the answer by alot

Comment: Note to self: maybe $m_0/\beta$ would have been a better parameter because it is the time it takes to fully evaporate.

Comment: I'm thinking the formula F = dp/dt assumes that the (F) is responsible for the change in (p).  In this case, the rate of change of the mass is independent of (F). The instantaneous acceleration changes with the mass: a = dv/dt = F/($m_o$ - βt).  Integrating dv = F(dt)/($m_o$ - βt), I get v = (F/β)ln[($m_o$/($m_o$ - βt)].

Comment: The only reason you get f=ma in the first place is by assuming M is independant of time. Which isn't the case here   so @AccidentalTaylorExpansion is correct

Comment: I've been thinking about this abit  more. And I see where Bird is coming from. If a body A has a mass of A, the net acceleration for the standard formula is F/m, where F is DEFINED as the rate of change of momentum. With a variable mass, the very definition of force comes into question. For example, because normally we DEFINE force as rate of change of momentum. Which normally must ONLY correspond to an acceleration. But with a variable mass, you can have a "force" with no acceleration. *"Force"* as I would disagree this is a force.

Comment: Example: consider the body is moving with a constant speed, Ie the particular solution to the differential equation where a(t) = 0. $$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = \frac{dm}{dt} v$$ here there is a change of momentum. But no acceleration, obviously due to the fact that the mass is decreasing so momentum must decrease. When differentiating the momentum, And then setting it equal to what we would originally call "force", we are essentially forcing the equation to mean that the rate of change of momentum is a fixed value. But with the added complexities of the mass changing,

Comment: This doesn't really fit with the standard definition. So I would actually NOT call this "Force" but SETTING IT, to have a change of momentum

Comment: I would also argue that in the context of field theory. No external "force" is causing this change of momentum. Unless we redefine force so that it can change the mass? " e.g working backwards, given a particle is always moving at a constant speed but experiences a force ( rate of change of p) what is the change of mass? Would this definition actually be a better definition and could be used in conjunction with other various forms of ways mass can change?

Comment: and this is also conservation of momentum  nightmare lmao